# How to test for a NULL ptr in MSVC given the many magic numbers

Tags: c++, memory-management, msvcrt

Having used the MSVC runtime library for debugging for some time I am quite familiar with the many 'magic' numbers assigned to data when it is first allocated, release etc.

During debugging, all of these magic numbers are not equal to 0, and so they are all indistinguishable from validly allocated memory.

Is there a recommended/useful way to replace the old standby test
if ( ptr_2_some_bfr == NULL )
to verify that the pointer is still valid?

Edit to clarify:
After more thought & testing in one of my projects, I need to clarify the problem I am trying to address.
For some projects, I need to allocate a given buffer size, but only once, and then later on, if the buffer was allocated, I need to decide whether the buffer needs to be freed, but also, only once.
In the debug environment, the the code tested with if( bufPtr ) will be executed whether the buffer was freed or not because bufPtr will either be 0x?????? (ie a valid ptr) or 0xdddddd, or even 0xcececece
And, while deleting or freeing a nullptr will not cause any error, trying to delete or free a ptr set to one of these magic numbers by the run-time library,will cause an exception, whether it was never cleared, never allocated, allocated or freed properly.

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do (to detect an invalid pointer in your code) won't work easily because often a pointer will be a small offset of one of these magic numbers.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for. `NULL` is the value we assign to a pointer when we try to communicate that it points to nothing. A deallocated ptr is not necessarily set to any specific value (or even changed due to deallocation).

Comment: The "magic numbers" occur when your code didn't bother to initialize the variable to some sensical value.  It has arbitrary garbage, for VS in debug mode, that garbage has a regular pattern to aid you in figuring out what you've done wrong.

Comment: Design your code such that invalid pointers are always NULL.

Comment: `ptr_2_some_bfr == NULL` (or ==nullptr) is the correct test for a null pointer. What you may be referring to could be a _dangling pointer_ or an _uninitialized pointer_. In either case, dereferencing one of them to look at what they are pointing to is undefined behavior. If you do that you are already lost. Trying such a test further breaks your code. The recommendation is to use pointers with proper care and prefer smart pointers when applicable.

Comment: checking for invalid pointers at runtime ? this is an interesting video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM9zteeTCiI

Comment: If your data isn't zero-initialized in debug mode (i.e. those magic numbers are there), then your data isn't zero-initialized in release mode. So, as others have said, make sure you zero-initialize pointers so that you *can* check for null values. Did I mention zero-initializing yet?

Comment: IME msvc uses only `0xdddddddd` and `0xcececece` as values for invalid pointers in debug builds. If you want to find the place where your pointer becomes invalid, use data-breakpoints while it's still alive.

Comment: A null pointer value, by definition, compares as equal to zero in C++.   If the actual representation is not zero by other definitions (e.g. by checking all the bytes of the memory it occupies) then it is up to the implementation to ensure it compares equal to zero  (e.g.  `if (some_pointer)` will always test false if `some_pointer` is a null pointer).    Bear in mind that uninitialised variables are not guaranteed to be zero (let alone comparable with zero).

Comment: @Osyotr: yours seemed the most useful comment. I am well aware of the rest of the possibilities. In my case, the memory gets released in an unknown location and set to one of those magic numbers somewhere. In this specific case, the data break point will be my best option, but what I am trying to set up is a general test - usable even in debug mode - for when such things happen. On second thought, it likely would be unnecessary to define similar patterns to test against, since these issues need to be sorted out in any case on the spot.